# ZK Component Set Component Not Value

Tags: java, zk

It seems very simple and maybe silly. But I couldn't find a way to set reverse of the combobox disabled value into the *a*(id=add) visibility.

```
<combobox id="cb" model="@{cont.values}" autodrop="true" disabled="true" readonly="false" >
    <comboitem self="@{each=val}"  label="@{val.name}" />
</combobox>
<a id="add" iconSclass="icon-plus-sign" visible="${cb.disabled}"/>
```

- if combobox is disabled *a* is NOT visible
- if combobox is enabled *a* is visible

How to make this? The above form in my solution makes the exact opposite what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use EL expression NOT operator

```
visible="${not cb.disabled}"
```

Refer [here](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZUML%20Reference/EL%20Expressions/Operators) for more details about EL expression operators within ZUML

Update:  Here is a working sample

```
<zk>
    <combobox id="cb" disabled="true" readonly="false" >
       <comboitem label="Test 1" />
       <comboitem label="Test 2" />
       <comboitem label="Test 3" />
    </combobox>
    <a id="add" visible="${not cb.disabled}">Add</a>
</zk>
```

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work. I've tried the way you suggest and also with "!" but none.

Comment: I added a working sample to my answer. What do you mean by it doesn't work? Do you mean you don't see the `a` element at all? It maybe because the iconSclass is not applied correctly? Check the actual html output using browser developer tools.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. It didn't work again maybe it's because of something else, i couldn't figure out.

Comment: Again, please specify what didn't work. My sample above when you visit the zul page containing this code will NOT show the `a` component because combobox is disabled, that's it. Do you mean you can not dynamically disable/enable combobox and hence show on/off the `a` component? Because that would need additional code to work